# Long pause on restart between power on and BIOS screen. Doesn't happen on startup from shutdown state.

Tags: boot

I'm using an HP Elite 8300 SFF PC with a GPU, SSD, and RAM upgrade. It's also running windows 10.

On startup from a shutdown state, the computer boots up rather fast, taking me to the login screen within 10-15 seconds. However, when restarting, there's an approximately 1 minute long pause between the power on and the BIOS screen displaying the HP logo. It's just a black screen. Once the I see the BIOS screen, boot up continues as normal.

Very odd considering it boots up normally when turned on from the off state; the delay only occurs on restart. Anyone have any ideas on what I should look into to fix this?

Comment: Which version of windows (I assume you're using windows?) are you using?

Comment: @LPChip Windows 10

Answer (score 0):

As we know, Fast Startup combines elements of a cold shutdown and the hibernate feature. When you shut down your computer with Fast Startup enabled, Windows closes all applications and logs off all users, just as in a normal cold shutdown. At this point, Windows is in a state very similar to when it’s freshly booted up: No users have logged in and started programs, but the Windows kernel is loaded and the system session is running. Windows then alerts device drivers that support it to prepare for hibernation, saves the current system state to the hibernation file, and turns off the computer.

Depends on the computer, when a computer hibernates, it does not enter a fully powered down mode. Some versions of BIOS/UEFI work with a system in hibernation, it doesn't require the Power on self test.

Confirm with your manufacturer to see if the BIOS of the computer support hibernate.

If so, this issue could be related to Hardware's POST. Contact the manufacturer to do the hardware test.

Answer (score 0):

The question is old, but this method has work for me and I think the answer can help other people.
To fix that problem you need to disable "Embedded Security Device" configuration in BIOS Setup. Follow the below procedure:

> 1. Power on the PC and press the F10 key to enter in BIOS settings.
> 2. Using your arrows keys, navigate to Security -> Device Security and press Enter.
> 3. Use the right-arrow key and change the Embedded Security Device from Device available to Device Hidden.
> 4. When done, press the F10 key once to apply the change.
> 5. Then press Enter at Save Changes and exit option.
> 6. Press Enter once more (at 'Yes') to save the changes and exit from BIOS.

These steps and screenshots for those can be found on that source:
https://www.repairwin.com/fix-hp-elite-6200-8200-slow-restart-issue-on-windows-10/

Comment: Welcome to Super User. Please read [How to reference material written by others](https://superuser.com/help/referencing). You must block quote text that has been written by some else. See [Markdown help](https://superuser.com/editing-help). I've fixed it for you this time, but please pay attention to this in future.